# Is PhotoSwipe JS compatible with JQuery Mobile v1.4.2?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I've done heaps of testing on this and I'm almost sure that Jquery Mobile v1.4.2 is not compatible with the latest version of the Photoswipe Javascript library (or older versions).

I am trying to use the Jquery command for Photoswipe:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe){

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('div.gallery-page')
                .live('pageshow', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        options = {},
                        photoSwipeInstance = $("ul.gallery a", e.target).photoSwipe(options,  currentPage.attr('id'));

                    return true;

                })

                .live('pagehide', function(e){

                    var 
                        currentPage = $(e.target),
                        photoSwipeInstance = PhotoSwipe.getInstance(currentPage.attr('id'));

                    if (typeof photoSwipeInstance != "undefined" && photoSwipeInstance != null) {
                        PhotoSwipe.detatch(photoSwipeInstance);
                    }

                    return true;

                });

        });

    }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

</script>
```

And this all works ok if you are using the version of Jquery mobile (Javascript) that comes with the PhotoSwipe download package samples. But when I link to Jquery Mobile v1.4.2 it just kills the Photoswipe js library and it never fires/works, it just links straight to the image.

Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue? If so, is there a decent workaround the issue? Or perhaps I am not doing something right.

Comment: Anouncement from P-S  website----  Announcement: the new version of PhotoSwipe is under development and will be released in near future. To get notified about release - join the email newsletter or follow PhotoSwipe on Twitter. (posted on March 2014)

Comment: Thanks @Tasos, I am aware that they will be making another release soon. Anyway, I devised my own hack to get around this problem. I wanted to load each small gallery into the DOM using AJAX but I wasn't able to keep the images separate and all the galleries were getting mixed up. I just sued the simple just using the simple JQuery command 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Gallery1 a").photoSwipe();
});
</script>

and called photoswipe function multiple times for each gallery and changing the Gallery DIV ID (i.e. Gallery1, Gallery2, Gallery3).

Comment: Excellent -- i'm waiting to see the new version. It should be goo. cheers for the reply